# What is the Max number of Category bitmasks we can insert for the objects in games that contain more than 100 collisions

Tags: swift, scenekit, bitmask

I am concerned about the max number of category bitmasks I can provide to objects in a game that contains more than 100 objects. From all I've read, I understood that we have a 32 bit number (or 64 bit) that we can use for category bitmasks but we can only enable 1 bit in order to maintain the maths for collision bitmasks and contact bitmasks. What if I give a category bitmask of 0x1, 0x10, 0x11 to objects and then handle collisions with it. I already tried the following,

1. ball.scn,  categorymask = 1, collisionmask = 5
2. cone.scn,  categorymask = 3, collisionmask = 5
3. floor.scn, categorymask = 5, collisionmask = 4

What happens here that the ball and cone passes through the floor.

But when I do,

1. ball.scn,  categorymask = 1, collisionmask = 4
2. cone.scn,  categorymask = 2, collisionmask = 4
3. floor.scn, categorymask = 4, collisionmask = 3

They all collide with the floor.